# Append Multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, append

I need help regarding to append multiple csv files for different periods.
In my folder there are multiple csv files for 10 categories for different periods (Files are on monthly basis (eg.cat_1_202001.csv,cat_2_202001.csv,cat_3_202001.csv,...,cat_10_202002.csv,...)

till dec-21. I need to append files for each category from JAN-21 till DEC-21. how do  I do ?Also I need to filter only Ur_flag=1.

But it merging all the files . please help me to get it differently for each category .
eg.
for cat-1 from JAN-21 to DEC-21.
for cat-2 from JAN-21 to DEC-21.'''

**EDIT** : code from the comments :

```py
import pandas as pd
from os import chdir
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
#path of folder
path1=r"C:\Users\xyz1\Analysis\cat_Files_from_Gdrive"
filenames = glob.glob(path1 +"\*.csv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(files) for files in filenames])
df.columns
```

File Format:

[Here I'm attaching one image in which headers are visible and format of data. I hope this helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGdtZ.png)

Comment: That still doesn't say what the files look like? What do you mean by append? What do you mean by category? And what exactly do you want? A code writing service?

Comment: import pandas as pd
from os import chdir
import numpy as np
import glob
import os#path of folder
path1=r"C:\Users\xyz1\Analysis\cat_Files_from_Gdrive"
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
filenames = glob.glob(path1 + "\*.csv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(files) for files in filenames ])

Comment: I'm using this code but I was not able to post in question. this code is appending files for all cat but since  I need one file for each one cat which includes data from jan-dec.

Comment: @SA17 I edited your question to add the code you provided. Could you provide a sample of at least two files to concatenate (the header and a few lines for example) ? Because it helps us to understand the problem and check the solution.